# How to extract groupings for multiline strings and based on substring?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Below is a pattern of `multi-line` strings.

```
abcdef-001a.mno123.xyz.com
abcdef-001b.mno123.xyz.com
abcdef-001a.pqr123.xyz.com
abcdef-001b.pqr123.xyz.com
lkjh-001a.abc123.xyz.com
lkjh-001b.abc123.xyz.com
lkjh-001a.def123.xyz.com
lkjh-001b.def123.xyz.com
mnbg-001a.tyu123.xyz.com
mnbg-001b.tyu123.xyz.com
mnbg-001a.ijk123.xyz.com
mnbg-001b.ijk123.xyz.com
```

reg-ex `(.*)\.(.*)\.xyz\.com` matches for above pattern, where `group1` associated with multiple `group2` (Example: `abcdef-001a` associated with `mno123` and `pqr123`  )

how can we identify such pairing ?

```
Output1:

{'mno123':'pqr123', 'abc123':'def123', 'tyu123':'ijk123'}
```

As a next step, get all the such lines separated associated with above dictionary.

```
Output2:

output2_list1:
abcdef-001a.mno123.xyz.com
abcdef-001b.mno123.xyz.com

output2_list2:
abcdef-001a.pqr123.xyz.com
abcdef-001b.pqr123.xyz.com

output2_list3:
lkjh-001a.abc123.xyz.com
lkjh-001b.abc123.xyz.com

output2_list4:
lkjh-001a.def123.xyz.com
lkjh-001b.def123.xyz.com

output2_list5:
mnbg-001a.tyu123.xyz.com
mnbg-001b.tyu123.xyz.com

output2_list6:
mnbg-001a.ijk123.xyz.com
mnbg-001b.ijk123.xyz.com
```

It can be separate list or any other feasible best approach to store such. Here I just shown as separate list to get clear picture.

As above mentioned pattern, it can contain many such lines and also, where there could be many different `group1` associated to `group2`.

Comment: Are the strings always ordered like that? Or can `abcdef-001a.mno123.xyz.com` also be the last string? So with pairing you mean that there are no more than an `a` version and a `b` version? Can the same string occur more than once? "As a next step" does that mean you want to separate pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic:

1. import the re library so you can use regular expressions.
2. Let's assume that you are reading the lines from a file so you do these things for each line:
3. As you read in each line, use the match() function on each item, and capture the result as a match object.
4. Each time, use the group() function to extract the two groups of interest from the match object and store them in a dictionary as follows:
   chek the dictionary to see if group(2) is a key, and if not, add it, but always add group(1) to a list associated with
   that key.
5. After you finish reading all the lines and thus building the dictionary, you can just iterate over the dictionhary and print the grouping of all items from the list that is associated with
   each key.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. I did till step 4, and working on step 5 now. I believe there must be some smart way to handle with powerful reg-ex.

Comment: It is a bad idea in the professional word to build code that is unnecessarily compact as it makes that code hard to read later - in the real world, code needs to be maintained and your company does not give prizes for being obscure.